# Restor sql server database to point in time useing full backup

Tags: sql-server, restore, point-in-time

I take a full backup of my DB at 12:00 pm, then i made some changes between 12:00 pm and 03:00 pm.
Can i restore my DB to 02:00 pm using the full backup i take,
and how.

Comment: You need a Transaction Log backup to do Point in time restore: https://technet.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/ms190982(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 0):

To do point in time restore, only full backup is not enough. If you want to restore database at ecact 2pm through full backup at 3 pm, you need to have transactional backup at 2pm or differential backup. Only then you can have point in time restore

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to. Even to you did not take a log backup after your full backup, the log is there. Take a log backup now, which will cover everything between 12:00 and 3:00. Then restore the 12:00 full backup, followed by a log restore with stop at 2:00.